# Android Google Maps connection (doesn't show the map)

Tags: android, google-maps

When I try to open my app I got an "empty" map,
That means I don't see the map, I can see the zoom in and zoom out buttons but there is no map.
Please help, here is my code:

```
package com.example.hichride;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {


    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat = 40.8;
        double longi = -96.666;

        GeoP= new GeoPoint ((int) (lat * 1E6), (int)(longi * 1E6));

        mControl= mapV.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is the `logCat` logs,
as you can see there is a connection problem that I don't know how to fix it:

```
07-31 19:55:37.878: W/MapActivity(746): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@411fa278
07-31 19:55:37.918: V/MapActivity(746): Recycling map object.
07-31 19:55:38.178: I/MapActivity(746): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
07-31 19:55:38.188: E/MapActivity(746): Couldn't get connection factory client
07-31 19:56:26.201: W/System.err(746): IOException processing: 26
07-31 19:56:26.201: W/System.err(746): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
07-31 19:56:26.208: W/System.err(746):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you running on the emulator or the phone?  Did you use the correct API key in the layout file?  You need one key for when you are running from Eclipse since it uses the debug key to sign the app, you need a second key for when you deploy as an apk that uses your key for signing the app.

Comment: You indeed need to specify your API key. See here [Sign API Key](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

Comment: i runnung it in emulator and have only one key,        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/mapView"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="0NmEd53d3Zfop95WmxjcHHm01_p15_3U5hutJwQ"
                 /> should i use another one?

Comment: Where did the apiKey come from and oh btw you should NEVER post the apiKey. See the link from tolgap.

Comment: sorry, i got the apikey from google signup api site, i entered the MD5 code and got the apikey

Comment: The MD5 hash of what?  The one from the debug key in the SDK?

Comment: ok next question, can you open the browser on the emulator and open any web sites?  In other words, does it have an internet connection working?

Comment: 9 times out of ten for me when I have this problem it is the apiKey is incorrect.  so, if you ran this exact command:  keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore  then it should be working.

Comment: i dont have debug keystore, should i create one?, when i insert the comand i got "enetr the keystore password" what is the keystore password?

Comment: by default, keystore password = android